# joining 4 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to build search query for hotel rooms availibility but it seems that his query is way over my head, and i need 
help to build it. Note that there will be multiply hotels in the database.

Even that I am looking for available rooms, my idea was not to build availibilty table, but instead to use reserevation
table, and I assume that if the rooom is not in the reservation table, it is available. (If you have any suggestions about this solution
I would like to hear it)

I have the following fields in the search form:

area (represented with areaid), checkInDate, checkOutDate, rooms (how many rooms he need), adults and childrens.

Here are the tables that should be involved in this search:

room
roomType
reservationroom
hotels

Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `room` (
    `roomID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `hotelID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `roomtypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `roomNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `roomName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `roomDescription` text,
    `roomVisible` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`roomID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `roomtype` (
    `roomtypeID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `hotelID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `roomtypeName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `roomtypeAdults` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `roomtypeChildrens` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `roomtypeDescription` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`roomtypeID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `hotel` (
    `hotelID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `areaID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `hotelcategoryID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `hotelName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `hotelShortDescription` text,
    `hotelAddress` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`hotelID`),
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `reservationroom` (
   `reservationroomID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `reservationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `hotelID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `roomID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reservationroomID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=greek;
```

Please note that I have removed the unnecessery fields from the tables, to make the code shorter and more easier to read.

Can anyone point me how to build this query to find available rooms? While I do know how to make simple join, this query is way over my head, and any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regards, John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this...

```
 SELECT r.* FROM room r LEFT JOIN `reservationroom` rr ON r.`hotelID` = rr.`hotelID` AND r.`roomID` = rr.`roomID`
 WHERE ( rr.`reservationroomID` = '' OR rr.`reservationroomID` IS  NULL );
```

This will give you the list of rooms which are not reserved. This is giving you the list of available rooms in all the hotels. If you want the rooms in specific hotel then add a new clause in where condition for the column ***hotelid***.

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

The following query return number of available room which are not reserve

```
SELECT *
FROM room
WHERE roomID NOT in
    (SELECT roomID
     FROM reservationroom);
```